# Paypal restful apis canada, Not able to create app on developer.paypal.com

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have one mobile application. In which we have payment function. In our application we have below mentioned payment flow.

- User can add credit card, For this first we are calling Paypal api (https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token) to get token. As we got token then we are calling api (https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card) to get credit card details form paypal.
- We are sending response details to our server. Our server will store that response.
- Later from application if user want to pay then we are showing list of added card & user can select any of card.
- We are sending card id to our server & based on stored details our server call charge api of paypal for charge.

Till now we are using sandbox account which belongs to USA. But Now we want to create live app on paypal & for this we are using our original account which belongs to Canada. But in create app section on developer.paypal.com we are not able to create application. 
- Is this function of payment is not available in Canada ? If not then Please let us know how we can achieve it ? 
- Is there any alternate exists for above mentioned payment function ?

Please let us know how we can create app and get clientid & secret for above mentioned payment function .

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

REST API in PayPal for Credit Card is only allowable in US and UK Pro. Other country is not yet available.

Further information in [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/#direct-credit-card-payments).

Comment: Is there any way to achieve current payment flow using paypal ?

Comment: You can if you proceed with PayPal Payments Pro but it is integrated using NVP instead of REST

Comment: But I am using it for taxi booking app. Where user can pay via credit card.

Comment: Well, that is a requirement for the REST API in PayPal, only US and UK PRO account are allowed to use credit card features.

You can read it further here (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/#direct-credit-card-payments).